# Running two loops at the same time ? moving and traveling using loops

Tags: c++, loops, winapi

I am a first year Computer Engineer so I am a little bit amatuer in coding C++, anyway I am creating a game where there are two spaceships shooting each other. I currently succeeded making the first spaceship move by using a while loop and the GetASyncKeyState function. but now I am making the bullets travel. I used  for loop, and I did succeed in making the bullet travel upward. But there's a problem, I can't move the spaceship until the for loop stop or the bullet reach the top of the console window (I am using console btw). is there a way to both run the for loop and while at the same time ? or to run two different function at the same time since GameMovement() is for the movement of spaceship and BulletTravel() is for the bullet. and I am calling BulletTravel() from GameMovement().

```
void GameMovements()
{
bool FirstInitialization = true;
int Player1XCoordinate = 55, Player2XCoordinate = 55;
int Player1YCoordinateU = 28, Player1YCoordinateD = 29;


while (true)
{
    BulletPattern(Player1XCoordinate);

    if (FirstInitialization == true)
    {
        GameBorderAndStatus();
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateU);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateD);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";
        FirstInitialization = false;
    }

    //MOVEMENTS FOR PLAYER 1
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) && Player1XCoordinate != 16)
    {
        system("cls");
        GameBorderAndStatus();

        Sleep(10);
        Player1XCoordinate -= 3;
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateU);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateD);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) && Player1XCoordinate != 94)
    {
        system("cls");
        GameBorderAndStatus();
        Player1XCoordinate += 3;

        Sleep(10);
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateU);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateD);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) && Player1YCoordinateU != 24)
    {
        system("cls");
        GameBorderAndStatus();
        Player1YCoordinateU -= 2;
        Player1YCoordinateD -= 2;

        Sleep(10);
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateU);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateD);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) && Player1YCoordinateU != 28)
    {
        system("cls");
        GameBorderAndStatus();
        Player1YCoordinateU += 2;
        Player1YCoordinateD += 2;

        Sleep(10);
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateU);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinateD);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";
    }

 }
}

void GameBorderAndStatus()
{
       //Draw game border
      for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
      {
         SetCoordinate(15, i);
         cout << "|";
         SetCoordinate(104, i);
         cout << "|";
      }

 }

void BulletPattern(int Player1MuzzleLocation)
{
    for (int i = 25; i != 3; i--)
    { 
       Sleep(100);
       SetCoordinate(Player1MuzzleLocation + 3, i);

    }
}

 void SetCoordinate(int CoordinateX, int CoordinateY)
 {
     COORD Coordinate;
     Coordinate.X = CoordinateX;
     Coordinate.Y = CoordinateY;
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coordinate);
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure you are aware of this, but none of your "Game Code" that you are using (`GetAsyncKeyState`, `SetCoordinate`, etc) are standard C++. That means we have no idea what they are, or if there is any problem with how you are using them. I would honestly recommend that you speak to your instructor for guidance as there is very little that we can do to assist you in debugging your code with so many mystery functions.

Comment: @ChrisBritt it's summer and the class ended. I am only doing this to kill some time. any way, I thought you all would have know GetASyncKetState() so sorry about that. any way I will update the code with SetCoordinate() in it.

Comment: @Neo Since your code relies heavily on the Windows API, I've gone ahead and retagged your question to hopefully get you some better exposure from people familiar with the relevant functions. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't find it helpful.

Comment: @computerfreaker Good edit, I'm afraid I don't know windows API well enough to even recognize the functions. (I was just seeing some mystery functions from somewhere.)

Comment: @ChrisBritt Google would have demystified them for you pretty quickly. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using two different functions and moving one object within each, you might find better results keeping track of where each object should be, and using one function to draw both.

It's a little hard to tell what's going on in your code since some functions and variable declarations are missing (I don't see you ever actually drawing a bullet, for example - might be a bug in your `BulletPattern`?), but something like this might do the trick:

```
void GameMovements()
{
    while (true)
    {        
        //MOVEMENTS FOR PLAYER 1
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) && Player1XCoordinate != GAMEBOARD_LEFT)
        {
            Player1XCoordinate -= 3;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) && Player1XCoordinate != GAMEBOARD_RIGHT)
        {
            Player1XCoordinate += 3;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) && Player1YCoordinate != SPACESHIP_TOP)
        {
            Player1YCoordinate -= 2;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) && Player1YCoordinate != SPACESHIP_BOTTOM)
        {
            Player1YCoordinate += 2;
        }

        Sleep(10);

        UpdateBulletPosition();
        DrawObjects();
    }
}

void UpdateBulletPosition()
{
  //if the bullet hits the top of the screen, remove it
  if (bulletYCoordinate == GAMEBOARD_TOP)
  {
      bulletXCoordinate = 0;
      bulletYCoordinate = 0;
  }

  //I assume you're automatically generating bullets whenever possible; you'll have to adjust this conditional if that's not the case

  //no bullet? generate one
  if (bulletXCoordinate == 0)
  {
      bulletXCoordinate = Player1XCoordinate + 3;
      bulletYCoordinate = 25;
  }
  else
  {
      bulletYCoordinate--;

      Sleep(100);
  }
}

void DrawObjects()
{
        //wipe the screen and show status first
        system("cls");
        GameBorderAndStatus();

        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinate);
        cout << "   ^  \n";
        SetCoordinate(Player1XCoordinate, Player1YCoordinate + 1);
        cout << "^==|==^ \n";

        //only draw the bullet if there's a bullet there to draw
        if (bulletXCoordinate != 0)
        {
            SetCoordinate(bulletXCoordinate, bulletYCoordinate);
            cout << ".\n";
        }
}

const int GAMEBOARD_LEFT = 16;
const int GAMEBOARD_RIGHT = 94;
const int GAMEBOARD_TOP = 3;
const int SPACESHIP_TOP = 24;
const int SPACESHIP_BOTTOM = 28;

int Player1XCoordinate = 55, Player2XCoordinate = 55;
int Player1YCoordinate = 28;
int bulletXCoordinate = 0, bulletYCoordinate = 0;
```

I also made some tweaks to the rest of your code. Every case in your `if-else` block used the same basic drawing code, so I pulled that out of the `if-else` entirely. That also let me drop the entire initialization `if-else`.

I also dropped one of your vertical coordinates for the spaceship. You really don't need two; just keep track of the upper coordinate and draw the lower half of the ship at `Player1YCoordinate + 1`.

Finally, I replaced your hardcoded board edges with constants. Magic numbers are generally frowned upon; using named constants makes it easier to determine why you're using a given value in a given location, as well as making it easier to update the code in the future (perhaps you need to update for a different console size).

Comment: @Neo It's considered good practice to upvote an answer you find useful and accept as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: @CareyGregory I would love to upvote but I need atleast 15 reputations to upvote :(